# Emit default gap between items in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given a simple flexbox:

[image]

I want to emit the space between the img and the green area..
How can I do it with my code?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid;
  width: 1028px;
  margin: 0 auto; /* put the container on the middle */
}

.flex-container ul {
  padding-left: 0; /* avoud the default padding to the left */
  background: green;
}

.flex-container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
}

.flex-container img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cvO9xwB.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Shop</li>
      <li>Contact us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to remove the space between them? in that case, why do you have `width: 45%` for the `img`?

Comment: remove `width: 45%` and add a height to the image, for instance `height: 120px` and you'd get  about the same image size but *without* space between image and the nav

Comment: @kukkuz thanks! Could you explain the reason that using precentage mess it up?

Comment: The image becomes 45% of the flex child ( the `div` wrapping the `img`), so remaining width goes empty - you can see this while inspecting it...

Answer (score 0):

Give the `.flex-container` a `justify-content: space-evenly;` or `justify-content: space-around;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid;
  width: 1028px;
  margin: 0 auto; /* put the container on the middle */
}

.flex-container .img-wrap{
  width: 108px
  height: 110px
}

.flex-container ul {
  padding-left: 0; /* avoud the default padding to the left */
  background: green;
}

.flex-container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
}

.flex-container img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 45%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flex-container">
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://seeklogo.com/images/N/new-google-maps-icon-logo-263A01C734-seeklogo.com.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Shop</li>
      <li>Contact us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working.. for some reason there is a problem with the image.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. If you ensure that the image loads properly and is of the same dimensions as the demo image you provided, the CSS fits your use case.

Comment: @TalRofe I changed the image url and enforced a fixed `width` and `height` to ensure the image doesn't go out of bounds. This should illustrate that the CSS works.

Answer (score 0):

For a lazy fix you can do:

```
  <div style="margin-right: -132px">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cvO9xwB.png">
  </div>
```

Will play more with your code and will try to find a more elegant way of fixing it.
Will edit if I find anything.

EDIT:

```
.flex-container img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right; /*This fixes the image*/
  width: 45%;
}
```

I found out that when you resized the image it still keeps its width so this is why there is the space on the right.

Comment: Don't you think it's odd to use floats when flex box is already adopted by the OP and is designed to solve such use cases?